# freebase api - restore content by GUID

Tags: api, freebase

I'm trying to get topic details by guid, since it is the only parameter I've got from the client. Is it possible to get all details regarding topic by it's guid? I was trying with "trans raw" but very small amount of information were returned from freebase. Also, I was trying with mql:

```
https://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?query={"query":[{ "guid":"#9202a8c04000641f800000001b6c8698" }]}
```

But didn't had any success with that either. Any help here please?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the question of why you are asking to be paid for a job that you didn't know how to do, you should try something along the lines of this:

http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?q=%5B%7B%22guid%22%3A%22%239202a8c04000641f800000001b6c8698%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22name%22%3Anull%7D%5D

There's a large amount of documentation available on http://wiki.freebase.com on how to use the various APIs.

Also note that you are using a deprecated API which is going away, although that isn't an issue if this is a one-time task.

Comment: I figured it out, but thanks anyway!

By the way, freebase API is huge and very confusing. I don't have time for detail investigation and learning, that's why I asked a question here. In my opinion this site is created for this purpose, or I'm wrong?

Comment: If you figured it out, why not add your answer (and accept it) so that this question gets marked as answered and stops showing up in the unanswered list.